# QML application vs QML/C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm developing a Qt desktop application that interacts with a Bluetooth device. The interface of this application should be developed in QML.

This application should contain 2 modules:

1. A front end module: UI that will be developed in QML.
2. A back end module: Interaction and control of the Bluetooth device.

As the Qt framework contains an implementation of Bluetooth in QML (`BluetoothDiscoveryModel`, `BluetoothSocket` and `BluetoothService`) and C++ (`QBluetooth`...), I was wondering what do I choose between QML and C++ to implement the back end module, in terms of:

- Performance.
- Architecture of the application.

And is it safe to combine QML and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QML is faster for prototyping. The rule of thumb is, if possible, make it in QML, then if you have performance problems, port the functionality to C++.

As Bluetooth is fairly low in bandwidth and hardware demand you might get away with doing it in QML.

Two things which may mandate using C++:

- if your data requires more complex parsing
- as the documentation states "If excessive amounts of data are sent, the function may block sending."

Comment: I personally wouldn't use performance as the primary decision on which side to implement things on, but reliability and testability.
Tools for static code analysis, etc, are much more mature for C++, etc. Not even takling about JavaScript requiring 100% branch coverage just to be certain that there are not syntax errors.

Comment: My primary problem with QML hasn't been performance but memory usage, it is a hog, so I usually end up consolidating rather large QML files into a single C++ type. But the most important metric IMO is development time, and in this aspect QML is a tremendous saver, that's the only reason I am using it. I went from 95% C++ to 95% QML usage in production, and it is not only faster to develop but also faster to pinpoint bugs, since instead of hard crashes you get "something went wrong on this line", which is that much better than manual debugging.

Comment: Right, as long as one stays in QML and use declarative features it is fine, the problem I was pointing out is doing actual processing. Only very few people commit to the strict test driven development necessary to keep JavaScript functions working and maintainable.
Even bindings can be difficult in that regard as they are basically also JS functions and typos do not always lead to warnings

Comment: QML has many advantages, most of all that it's extremely fast for development. You can also make own C++ components available for QML, so there's no limit to what you can do. We've created a summary of what we've learned from creating many QML-driven apps for enterprise customers or own projects. You can find the developer guide with architecture best practices and tips for QML-driven apps [here](https://v-play.net/apps/avoid-cpp-models-qt).